# JoomGallery template warnings in Joomla 2.5

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I am new to Joomla and trying to buil a photo gallery in Joomla 2.5 using JoomGallery2.0. Its giving the below warnings- 
`Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\svn\Joomla\components\com_joomgallery\router.php on line 27` and few more warnings like
`Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method JHTMLJoomGallery::anchor() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\svn\Joomla\libraries\joomla\html\html.php on line 222`

`Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\svn\Joomla\components\com_joomgallery\helpers\html\joomgallery.php on line 752`

Can anybody help me out. If not suggest a better non commercial photo gallery template for Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you using xampp just adjust your settings in php.ini. So open the php ini and change the  error_reporting and display_errors.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even after doing these changes, getting same result. I reinstalled and tried again but no use.

Comment: hmm, that's really odd. Could you try the following? Go to Global Configuration in your Joomla admin, click on the Server tab and set "error reporting" to "None" in the "Server Settings". If that doesn't work try adding "php_flag display_errors off" in your htaccess. Not sure why it's staying on for you. Oh for that setting in php.ini to take effect you would need to restart Apache so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot Trev. I changed Global Configuration setting. Now its not showing any errors :)